# vb.net WebBrowser Open link in default browser

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I want to show image ads in my program, I use the Web Browser tool and put a link advertising. I want to open ads links in the user's default browser.

In Web Browser "URL" I use : "http://name.com/ads.html#num1"

and this "num1" is :

```
<div id="num1">
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"> 
        <img src="img/num1.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I need to open this link in default browser.

Comment: i assume clicking on the link opens it in IE. even if it not the *default* browser. is there some specific reason why you want to avoid opening it in IE?

Comment: Is the html page managed by you? Can you edit it or is it a third party page?

Comment: @Andrea yes managed by me

Comment: @inquisitive we have problems with css3 and jquery in IE

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebBrowser's `Navigating` event and try to cancel the event redirecting it to the default browser.

Problem is this event occurs every time a webpage is loaded in WebBrowser control. To avoid redirection on each `navigating` event you could filter on target url (if this is an acceptable solution for you):

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
    If e.Url.ToString = "http://google.com/" Then
        Process.Start(e.Url.ToString)
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

In order for this solution to work you also have to change your html page switching target from `_blank` to `_self` otherwise `Navigating` error wouldn't be triggered:

```html
<a href="http://google.com" target="_self"> 
    <img src="img/num1.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: thanks ِAndrea , but i need to edit links from my external html file, because i want to change this ads every month. if we can change : "if e.Url.ToString = " to "if the link contains google.com" ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been a long time but
expanding on Andrea's answer i made it work for all URLs this way:

```
Private docComplete As Boolean = False
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        docComplete = True
    End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
    If docComplete Then
        ' Process.Start(e.Url.ToString)
        openULR(e.Url.ToString) 'start process by a default browser
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

just to make sure links trigger the event i replace _blank tags in html to _self like this:

```
 html = Replace(html, "target=""_blank""", "target=""_self""")
```